# Finite p-th variation implies zero-valued q-th variation.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

**The Question**: Let $X$ be a continuous process, and suppose $0 < p < q$.

Prove the case $V_t^p(X) < \infty \implies V_t^q(X) = 0$.

**Definitions**:

The standard setup.

$\Pi := \{t_0,t_1,...,t_N\}$ where $0 = t_0 \leq t_1 \leq ... \leq t_N = t$.

$||\Pi|| := \text{max}_{1 \leq i \leq N}|t_i - t_{i-1}|$

$V_t^a(X) := \lim_{||\Pi||\to 0}\sum_{i=1}^N |X_{t_i} - X_{t_{i-1}}|^a$

**My Current Progress**:

$V_t^q(X) = \lim_{||\Pi||\to 0}\sum_{i=1}^N |X_{t_i} - X_{t_{i-1}}|^p |X_{t_i} - X_{t_{i-1}}|^{q-p}$.

By the Holder Inequality, for $\frac1a + \frac1b = 1$:

$$V_t^q(X) = \lim_{||\Pi|| \to 0}\sum_{i=1}^N|X_{t_i}-X_{t_{i-1}}|^p|X_{t_i}-X_{t_{i-1}}|^{q-p} 
$$
$$
V_t^q(X) \leq \lim_{||\Pi|| \to 0}\Big[\sum_{i=1}^N(|X_{t_i}-X_{t_{i-1}}|^p)^a\Big]^\frac1b \Big[\sum_{i=1}^N(|X_{t_i}-X_{t_{i-1}}|^{p-q})^b\Big]^\frac1a 
$$
$$
= \lim_{||\Pi|| \to 0}\Big[\sum_{i=1}^N(|X_{t_i}-X_{t_{i-1}}|^p)^a\Big]^\frac1b \lim_{||\Pi|| \to 0}\Big[\sum_{i=1}^N(|X_{t_i}-X_{t_{i-1}}|^{p-q})^b\Big]^\frac1a 
$$
**My Request**:

Please help me to progress further on this interesting problem.

Comment: Hint: Hölder inequality.

Comment: @did Thanks. Do you have any tips on how to progress furtheR?

Comment: Yes: choose your $a$ and $b$ such that a factor of the RHS is a power of the $q$-variation. This allows to bound $V_t^q(X,\Pi)$ by a power of $V_t^p(X,\Pi)$, for every $\Pi$. Then take the supremum over $\Pi$.

Comment: @Did Assuming $ \lim_{||\Pi|| \to 0}\Big[\sum_{i=1}^N(|X_{t_i}-X_{t_{i-1}}|^p)^a\Big]^\frac1a \lim_{||\Pi|| \to 0}\Big[\sum_{i=1}^N(|X_{t_i}-X_{t_{i-1}}|^{p-q})^b\Big]^\frac1b$
How would one choose $a, b$ for the desired result? As user157279 pointed out, choosing $ap=q$ will result in the exact same equation and choosing $(q-p)b=p$ will result in $ \lim_{||\Pi|| \to 0}\Big[\sum_{i=1}^N|X_{t_i}-X_{t_{i-1}}|^{\frac{p^2}{2p-q}}\Big]^\frac{2p-q}{p} \lim_{||\Pi|| \to 0}\Big[\sum_{i=1}^N|X_{t_i}-X_{t_{i-1}}|^{p}\Big]^\frac{q-p}{p}$

Comment: The right factor is finite by assumption but we can't say anything about the other factor, can we?

Answer (score 0):

This is more like a comment but there are a few typos in the above.

It should read

$\lim (\sum ((X_{t_i} - X_{t_{i-1}})^p)^a)^{1/a} + \lim (\sum ((X_{t_i} - X_{t_{i-1}})^{q-p})^b)^{1/b}$ if Holder's inequality were to be applied properly.

But if one were to set $ap=q$ then $b = \frac{q}{q-p}$ whereas if $b(q-p)=q$ then we would be in the same position as before. This value of $a$ and $b$ does not render the RHS to be in the form that Did mentioned in the above comment - the RHS has a factor of a power of the $q$-variation and a factor of a power of the $p$-variation.

Am I mistaken or was I not clever enough?